# Why is Eclipse's Run button not working?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

I use Eclipse Luna and everything was working fine until today when I saw this error message while trying to run my code:

[image: Error message dialog:]

When I dismissed the message, clicking the run and debug buttons did nothing at all. I restarted Eclipse, but that did nothing.

After trying to find the source of the error, it seems that restarting the whole computer seems to "reset" everything. The first time I open Eclipse after a restart, the run button works fine for one run, but after that first run if I hover the cursor over the run button, I get the above error message and the run button stops working. Strangely, clicking the down arrow next to the run button and selecting my project works all the time, regardless of the error message.

Has anybody else been having this problem? What could be causing this?

UPDATE 1:
The workspace .log file entry starts with:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2014-08-21 10:34:50.212
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Compute launch button tooltip".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemHandler.handle(ProblemHandler.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemReporter.handle(ProblemReporter.java:2343)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemReporter.handle(ProblemReporter.java:2406)
```

and continues on with a huge stack trace which ends with:

```
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.LaunchingResourceManager.computeLabels(LaunchingResourceManager.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.LaunchingResourceManager$1$1.run(LaunchingResourceManager.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

UPDATE 2:
Reinstalling did not fix anything. In fact, the error only occurs when one certain source file is open in the Editor... I tried removing class members one by one and the error only occurs if one specific method is present. This method is pretty long (176 LOC), and everything works fine if I remove at least 70 LOC. Breaking the method up into several helper methods does not help. I have never seen anything like this before, does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Never had this problem... But I would recommend re-installing eclipse... Just make a copy of your workspace

Comment: Sounds like some important file or something is missing or corrupt

Comment: This link is old but, same sympthoms. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=270446. Did you install any plug-ins? What is the bundle that you're using?

Comment: Have you checked the log file for the complete details of the error? (`workspace/.metadata/.log`)

Comment: I don't have any plug-ins, and it's just Eclipse Standard 4.4.0. I will reinstall and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Reinstalling did not help... I tried more troubleshooting and updated my original post

Answer (score 0):

If this is still not working for you, update to Eclipse Oxygen 3A (April 2018), and it will work for you.